# create dialog in Composer on event CreateHandoffStatus

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I want to crate trigger in composer for event when handoff completed. Event sent from handoff library using CreateHandoffStatus with status "completed". How to configure trigger and how to check condition that handoff completed? Once trigger happen I want to run dialog with post human conversation.

Comment: You should use the Activities trigger when you want to take action on receipt of the `handoff` activity type.

Comment: Activities triggers doc [Activities triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-events-and-triggers?tabs=v2x#:~:text=to%20define%20triggers.-,Activities%20triggers,-Activities%20triggers%20are)

Comment: For additional information, see the [Activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-define-triggers#activities) trigger in the [Define triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-define-triggers) article.